# Discord command unable to read array arguments, gives a console error "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm just playing around with a discord bot command idea that I've had. Basically it uses the axios packages to sent viewers to an ebay listing (entertainment purposes). I'm using discordjs v13.6.0 and the latest axios packages. The command is a slash based command that goes /ebay => listing => viewers. Unsure where exactly it crashes, but I'm under the assumption it's crashing when I input the specified viewers sent because it'll give an error in the terminal "if (args.length < 3 { TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') I'm assuming that's because length isn't define, but unsure exactly how I'll go about fixing that. Here's my following code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const axios = require("axios")
const { CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "ebay",
    description: "Use this command to send viewers to your ebay listing",
    permission: "USE_APPLICATION_COMMANDS",
    options: [
        {
            name: "listing",
            description: "Input the link to your listing",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "viewers",
            description: "Input the amount of viewers",
            type: "INTEGER",
            required: true
        }
    ],

    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute (interaction, msg) {
        const { options } = interaction;
        const listing = options.getString("listing")
        const viewers = options.getInteger("viewers")
        let args;
        if (msg && msg.content) {
            args = msg.content.split(' ');
        }

        if (args.length < 3) {
            errorEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#E80E0E")
            .setTitle('Error Found! ❌')
            .setDescription(`Viewers cannot be sent at this time, make sure you're inputting the correct link`)
            interaction.reply({ embeds: [ebayEmbed] });
            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < args[2]; i++) {
            await axios.get(args[1], {
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.5195.102 Safari/537.36'
                }
            });
        }

        ebayEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#5104DB")
            .setTitle("Successfully Sent Viewers! ")
            .setDescription(`**${viewers}** have been successfully sent to **${listing}**!`)

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [ ebayEmbed ] });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `msg` come from? Can you show its definition.

Comment: I'm not too sure. The code was written on DiscordJS V12 a while back and I pulled the source and reworked to DiscordJS V13

Comment: Your logic deals with `msg`, if you don't know what `msg` is and how it works how will we know any better?

Comment: I'm just assuming, but I think msg logic involves discordjs's messageCreate, which I'm converting this command for the original (prefix) + {commandname} trigger to / slash command involving discord's interactionCreate, so I guess my question is how do I go about converting the msg logic to work with interaction